# dapper c# returns rows found not rows affected

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I have a simple stored procedure which does update on a table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_v1`(
out v_changed_rows int
)
BEGIN
    update mytable
    set color = 'green'
    where id = 964291; 
    set v_changed_rows= ROW_COUNT();
END
```

Calling this stored procedure from mysql workbench gives correct rows affected(i.e. first time it will return 1 and hence forth returns 0 because I'm updating it with the same value and hence no change)

[image]

The problem comes when I call this stored procedure from C# 
[image]

I tried calling this query in a `for` loop and each time it returns `1`.
How do I get the rows affected by the query, not the rows found by the query? 
Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I guess I'll try that too. We use dapper as our ORM

Comment: So I tried it with ado.net and I'm still getting `1` as the answer. So the problem lies with mysql end?

Comment: Check the connection string and check it is pointing at the database you think that it is. Also check the stored proc definition there is what you think it is. And run `select * from mytable    where id = 964291;` against that database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is such note for [ROW_COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)  function:

> For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the
>   number of rows actually changed. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS
>   flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the
>   affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by
>   the WHERE clause.

Although it says that number of actually changed rows is returned by default, for MySql .Net client the default behavior is to return number of rows matched by WHERE clause. This should be due to the value of `client_flag` parameter passed to [mysql_real_connect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-connect.html).

You could change this behavior by explicitly setting [UseAffectedRows](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/count-changed-rows-instead-of-found-rows/) to `True` in your connection string:

> server=localhost;user
>   id=test;password=test;database=test;UseAffectedRows=True

I've tried and it works perfectly fine both with ADO.NET and Dapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your stored procedure `RETURN @@ROWCOUNT`
And inside your method do smth like that:

```
var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
dynamicParameters.Add("@UpdatedCounter", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
var result = await _connection.ExecuteAsync("sp_Update", dynamicParameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
int updatedCounter = dynamicParameters.Get<int>("@UpdatedCounter");
return updatedCounter;
```